# Symfony php app/console server:run

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to run the server but keep getting these messages when running php app/console server:run:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/symfony_demo/app/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/symfony_demo/app/autoload.php on line 11
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/symfony_demo/app/console:0
PHP   2. require() /var/www/html/symfony_demo/app/console:17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/symfony_demo/app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/symfony_demo/app/autoload.php on line 11
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/symfony_demo/app/console:0
PHP   2. require() /var/www/html/symfony_demo/app/console:17
```

If I run php bin/console server:run I get this message:
`Could not open input file: bin/console`

The only change I have made recently was use winSCP to copy my files from the remote server to my local PC. Can someone help me with the errors?

EDIT: Like an idiot I copied over the wrong project.
EDIT: Still didn't fix my issue.

Comment: Are you just going through the Symfony tutorials? Or did you actually have a "working" project?

Comment: I had a working project. Now it does not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely didn't run `composer install` or forgot to copy the *vendor* directory.